# Different Footer on different pages

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, footers

I have a word 2013 file
need to have the first 2 pages without Footer
and then start a different footer for each of the rest pages

Comment: Word doesn't support doing this.  You can make the first page and the rest of the pages different [though](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HdiqY.png).

Comment: @ramhound Really? Is there some problem with sections breaks?

Comment: @DavidPostill no, its just not supported. When you go to the header footer insert page, it will tell you: "first page differently" but not second page differently.

Comment: @DavidPostill - I didn't think to create different sections of the paper.  That would indeed do what the author wants.

Comment: @LPChip Not if you use different sections ...

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I have different footers on different pages

Use [section breaks](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/291184).

> You can use section breaks to change the layout or formatting of a page or pages in your document. For example, you can lay out part of a single-column page as two columns. You can separate the chapters in your document so that the page numbering for each chapter begins at 1.
>
> You can also create a different header or footer for a section of your
> document.

Source [Insert a section break](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Insert-a-section-break-eef20fd8-e38c-4ba6-a027-e503bdf8375c).